# How to include method return value when saving a model instance with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am currently working on a project that uses [Spring Data MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/). Using the model given below, how can I achieve that the result of someMethod() is stored in the database? Currently, the stored model instance will only include `valueA` and `valueB`.

```
@Document
public class SomeClass {

    private String valueA;

    private String valueB;

    // getter and setter omitted...

    public String someMethod() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Spring Data persists all field values as they are what makes up the state of the object. So one very obvious and simple way would be to assign the value to a field.

Alternatively you can configure Spring Data to used the object with property access (invoking getters and setters) by either annotating the type or individual getters or setters with `@AccessType(Type.PROPERTY)`.

Not that this won't work in your case out of the box as `someMethod()` obviously doesn't adhere to the property accessor spec, so you'd have to rename the method to `get…()`.